# Ejecutar operacion sqlite3 en python antes de mostrar datos en un QTableView

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas noches comunidad.

Tengo una consulta en sqlite3 que la realizo en la tabla Ventas la cual es la siguiente:

```
import sqlite3


fecha ="12/08/2018"


conexion = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")
cursor = conexion.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Ventas WHERE Fecha= ?",(fecha,))
for i in cursor:
    print(i)
```

y tengo la funcion que muestra la tabla Ventas:

```
dbs = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
dbs.setDatabaseName('Users.db')
dbs.open()

model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable('Ventas')
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
model.select()
tabla.setModel(model)
```

Quiero saber como podria mostrar en este caso unicamente los datos de la consulta que realizo en el codigo de arriba, que seria mostrar los datos unicamente de la fecha establecida. Y no que muestre todos los datos de la Tabla

Comment: ¿qué tipo de columna es la columna `Fecha`?

Comment: @eyllanesc, es un string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas hacer un filtro debes usar el metodo [`setFilter()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter)

```
fecha ="12/08/2018"
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable('Ventas')
model.setFilter("Fecha= \"{}\"".format(fecha))
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
model.select()
tabla.setModel(model)
```